# Windows 7 user account no longer on Welcome Screen

Tags: windows-7, windows, user-accounts

**Problem Description:**

Windows 7 Ultimate on Hyper-V Virtual Machine hosted by a 2008 Server R2 SP1.

It was running last night under my account "Foo" when an automatic reboot had occurred due to Windows Update running overnight. I was presented with the welcome screen but the user account Foo is no longer displayed as a logon option, just Administrator.

**Details:**

Windows Update installed these 2 updates: KB2533552 and KB2534366. Subsequent reboots did not fix the issue.

I can see the account Foo in *Computer Management/Local Users and Groups* and it looks normal (is not disabled), but I don't see it in *Control Panel/User Accounts* and *Family Safety/User Accounts/Manage Accounts*. All I see there is *Administrator* and *Guest* (off). The profile folder is still there.

I don't feel comfortable doing what is recommended [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itproui/thread/88903fce-9722-4774-9390-02adfeb84e46/). Besides, `C:\Users\%username%` or `C:\Users\Temp` do not exist on this machine.

Things here look normal: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList` - no keys with `.bak` extensions.

When I try a system restore to a point before the Windows Update I get "System Restore did not complete successfully..." "The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable".

Any ideas on how to make the Foo user account show up again so I can log on with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that the "Foo" account lost it's membership to the Administrators group. This is what got changed, apparently, by Windows Update. Once I added Foo back in to the Administrators group it appeared back on the welcome screen.

Answer (score 0):

I'd first run a `chkdsk /f` on the drive to make sure the file system is still good. Then try this ([source](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-security/make-windows-7-show-user-list-on-login-screen-not/63cea659-f6a0-412d-a0b1-952a26c1df44)):

> I managed to fix it by
>   deleting a key from the registry.
>   Click the Start menu and type
>   regedt32.  Navigate to the following
>   key.
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows
>   NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList In the
>   profile list, there was one named
>   .DEFAULT with no data within it.  I
>   deleted this key rebooted and all of
>   my user icons were back on the logon
>   screen.
>
> Of course, you should have a
>   backup of the registry key before
>   deleting.  I don't know why this
>   suddenly changed. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Randolf. I did a chkdsk /f on the Hyper-V host machine (no disk problems found), chkdsk doesn't seem to be allowed to run on the VM directly. Rebooted, no change in behavior.